# ExecStart has a '-' prefix but the unit is still failed

Tags: systemd

I have overridden the dnf-makecache not to put my system in a failed state every time there is a problem on the internet (shocker!) but it seems to be ignored.

```
# sc cat dnf-makecache.service
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/dnf-makecache.service
[Unit]
Description=dnf makecache
# On systems managed by either rpm-ostree/ostree, dnf is read-only;
# while someone might theoretically want the cache updated, in practice
# anyone who wants that could override this via a file in /etc.
ConditionPathExists=!/run/ostree-booted

After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
Environment="ABRT_IGNORE_PYTHON=1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer

# /etc/systemd/system/dnf-makecache.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer
[root@lxd10 ~]# man systemd.service
[root@lxd10 ~]# sc cat dnf-makecache
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/dnf-makecache.service
[Unit]
Description=dnf makecache
# On systems managed by either rpm-ostree/ostree, dnf is read-only;
# while someone might theoretically want the cache updated, in practice
# anyone who wants that could override this via a file in /etc.
ConditionPathExists=!/run/ostree-booted

After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
Environment="ABRT_IGNORE_PYTHON=1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer

# /etc/systemd/system/dnf-makecache.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer
```

but it still fails and the system state is degraded

```
Jun 28 09:08:35 lxd10.2e-systems.com systemd[1]: dnf-makecache.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 28 09:08:35 lxd10.2e-systems.com systemd[1]: dnf-makecache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 09:08:35 lxd10.2e-systems.com systemd[1]: Failed to start dnf makecache.
```

but the manual explicitly says the the exit code will be ignored if the exec path is prefixed by a dash. What am I doing wrong? Maybe because it is run by a timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`systemd.service(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=):

> Unless `Type=` is `oneshot`, exactly one command must be given. **When
> `Type=oneshot` is used, zero or more commands may be specified.** Commands
> may be specified by providing multiple command lines in the same
> directive, or alternatively, this directive may be specified more than
> once with the same effect. **If the empty string is assigned to this
> option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of
> this option will have no effect.**
> [...]

Likewise, from [`systemd.unit(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples):

> Note that **for drop-in files**, if one wants to **remove entries from a
> setting that is parsed as a list** (and is not a dependency), such as
> `AssertPathExists=` (or e.g. **`ExecStart=` in service units**), one needs to
> **first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one that
> is to be removed.**
> [...]

So with current OP's `override.conf` file since the type is *oneshot*, `ExecStart=` is now a two-elements list: `/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer` and `-/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer`. [This](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) then applies:

> If **more than one command is specified**, the commands are invoked
> sequentially in the order they appear in the unit file. If one of the
> commands fails (and is not prefixed with "-"), other lines are not
> executed, and the unit is considered failed.

As the original command without `-` is still executed, when it fails the service fails.

To *replace* it, the `override.conf` file should include something like below:

```ini
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer
```

Comment: Thanks, as it usually goes, I have already figured it out by myself, by a virtue of writing a question about it ;)